# Jetty - 9 BAD REQUEST ERROR with Volley server

Tags: java, android, jetty, android-volley, dropwizard

I have upgraded my dropwizard to 0.8 that uses jetty -9 server. 
I am using volley server 1.0.15 to send my JSON request from my app. 
My problem is when I send any JSON from volley the api throws 400 while when I send same request from  postman it is working fine.

> WARN  [2015-05-08 14:16:18,223] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: Illegal    character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@642bbd0f[p=1,l=78,c=8192,r=77]={\x16<<<\x03\x00\x00I\x01\x00\x00E\x03\x00\xBfE\x8e\x82\xCb\xE3\xCa...\x07\xC0\x11\x00/\x005\x00\x05\x00\xFfV\x00\x01\x00>>>-1\r\nContent-Lengt...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
>   WARN  [2015-05-08 14:16:18,223] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp@650d154b{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}

and my code to make volley request

```
JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();
userDetails.put("email", "tasneem");
userDetails.put("password", "1234");
userDetails.put("deviceId", "243243");
userDetails.put("version", "4.4.4");
userDetails.put("platform", "Android");
JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,     Constants.URL_LOGIN, userDetails, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    Log.e(TAG, volleyError.toString());
    mListener.onError(volleyError);
  }
}) {
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
  }
};
```

Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

And can anyone tell me how to trace the complete request without creating custom volley request, is there any way?

Comment: That error means that your client is not sending an HTTP request.  If you can capture your network traffic (easiest at the server side), you should have more information to work with.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, but the same volley request was working perfect before and can you please tell me way to intercept the request. I am not able to track, what I can see is the request that I have sent and that looks perfect.

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to capture the traffic in question.  The error is telling you that (during the raw HTTP request parsing) Jetty encountered a byte 0x16 (hex) and rejected the request (as that byte is invalid, per spec, anywhere in an HTTP request header)

Comment: Another thing to look for is scheme mismatch.  Such as attempting to talk HTTPS (SSL+HTTP) to a non HTTPS connector (such as normal, plain, HTTP/1.1 with no SSL).

Comment: any update on this? I'm seeing the exact same errors in the logs. were you able to resolve this? what did you change to make it work? @JoakimErdfelt what is the recommended way to handle a scheme mismatch?

Comment: @Hristo a testcase that replicates this is going to be important to help resolve it.  This include the servers setup/configuration, along with the client setup/configuration.

Comment: what's the best way to give you that information? StackOverflow question, pastebin, file a bug on Bugzilla?

Comment: @Hristo capture the traffic with Wireshark, attach it to a bugzilla, we'll work on this at bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt... done: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471081

Answer (score 1):

I traced the packets sent in wireshark and found that in header, `Content-Type` was mentioned twice.

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; HTC Desire 526GPLUS dual sim Build/KOT49H)\r\n
.
. 
.
```

Removing the overriden method getHeaders() worked

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
return headers;
}
```

The override is not required because in `com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.java`, `Content-Type` is already set to `application/json; charset=utf-8` and it seems dropwizard 0.8 does not take same header twice.